# Spring HttpSecurity - Filter Dependency Injection

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, dependency-injection

In my web application, I have created a custom filter for adding the current login details to `org.slf4j.MDC` . The application uses spring boot and the spring security is configured purely using annotations.

Here is the relevant parts of spring configuration,

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
    @Inject
    private CustomFilter customFilter;
    //
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.addFilter(customFilter);
    }
}
```

The above code doesn't work. I get an exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set com.example.web.filter.CustomFilter field com.example.config.SecurityConfiguration.customFilter to com.sun.proxy.$Proxy202
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:164) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:168) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:81) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:741) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:505) [spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    ... 76 more
```

But this one however does work.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
    //
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.addFilter(new CustomFilter());
    }
}
```

In my knowledge it is recommended to let spring container manage initialization which is why I tried the first approach. Can anyone tell me why dependency injection is failing for `addFilter()` method?

PS: I have tried with `addFilterAfter` method also, but get the same result. As my CustomFilter extends `SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter`, I use just `addFilter()`.

Comment: You can use this annotation in Spring but it also has it's own annotation for DI. The beans used by this annotation should be configured by Spring

Comment: @RomanC Yes using `@Autowired` instead of `@Inject` is working as expected. But why?

Comment: What is the `@Inject`? Which package it from?